# Reverse the given number in php

Tags: php

I am using the below code for reverse the order of given number.

```
$a=$_GET['get'];
if($a>0)
{
$b=$a%10;
echo $b;
$a=$a/10;
}
```

But i ll get only last digit,can any one help me. If ok means please explain how this process is going?

Comment: USe `while` instead of `if` loop for that.

Comment: You just need to `echo $a` or just use `strrev`

Comment: what does reverse mean ?

Comment: `echo intval(strrev(strval($number)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is (and mind the use of `floor()` here):

```
$a=$_GET['get'];
while($a>0)
{
    $b=$a%10;
    echo $b;
    $a=floor($a/10);
}
```

Or simply just do like said in the comments:

```
$a=$_GET['get'];
echo strrev($a);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [strrev](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php) function in PHP

Try this :-

```
<?php

$a = $_GET['get'];
echo strrev((string) $a);

?>
```

OR if you don't want to use strrev then :

```
<?php
$string = (string)$_GET['get'];
$length = strlen($string);

for ($i=($length-1) ; $i >= 0 ; $i--) {
  echo $string[$i];
}

?>
```